# How are paths determined on a remote machines?

Tags: networking, network-protocols

How are paths determined on a remote machines?

I have been assigned a network loaction.  Let's call it \wassup\test1

I assume that wassup is the ame of the computer.  The question I have is this.  How can I determine what the local path from the point of view of the remote machine would be for "test1".  For example, how would I know if it is c:\test1 or d:\test1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot know this from the client. Take a related example: which local path on the server does the below link point to?

[How are paths determined on a remote machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026500/how-are-paths-determined-on-a-remote-machines)

Comment: Exactly. And to go one step further, the local path doesn't even have to be on the server - it could be on a total different computer. There's no way to determine that from the outside.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  The remote machine might be an OS that doesn't even use drive labels like that.

Answer (score 0):

In a general case, you can't. The remote admin should be able to conceal it ... except in the obvious case of the ill-named "administrative shares" in Win (i.e. c$, d$, etc).