# Joining remote paths in Java

Tags: java, path

I'm using the FTP library provided by Apache (commons-net). I want to check if a file exists on the FTP server so I use the `listFiles` method of `FTPClient`:

```
ftpClient.listFiles(remoteFileDir + "\\" + fileName);
```

The current directory is the FTP server root directory. So, the value of `remoteFileDir` is a path relative to this root directory.

My question concerns the merge between the remote directory path and the file name. What is the right way to do it? For a local file, I would do:

```
File file = new File(remoteFileDir,fileName);
```

but here it doesn't work since when I call `file.getAbsolutePath()`, I get an absolute path for the file in the local current directory which is not what I want. Also, I guess the merging has been done according to my local environment.

PS: I looked at [How are paths determined on a remote machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026500/how-are-paths-determined-on-a-remote-machines) but it doesn't help me.

Thanks

Comment: What problem exactly are you trying to solve? Using File object to represent anything other than a local file is definitely a no-no. But if using \\ or the changeWorkDir methods work - why bother ?

Comment: @LordDoskias Using \\ works in my case, what about other FTP servers? Will it still work? Concerning the changeWorkingDirectory method, I just discovered it but I want to hear what other developers think, maybe there is an issue I don't see for now.

Comment: I'd advise that you use "/" single forward slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the method changeWorkingDirectory of FTPClient.

```
ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(remoteFileDir);
FTPFile[] names = ftpClient.listFiles(fileName);
```

In this case, I don't have to specify a delimiter.